# Python SQL variable

Tags: python, sql

```
def copy_sql_db(storage_connection, mysql_connection, date):
    cursor = storage_connection.cursor()
    mysql_cursor = mysql_connection.cursor()

    if date == "ALL":
      cursor.execute("""select name, test_time, id from test_table""")
    else:
      cursor.execute("""select name, test_time, id from test_table where test_time > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL date day)""")
    ...
```

I do not know what to search for to get the variable **date** that I pass into my function, **copy_sql_db** into my else: cursor.execute...when I run the script created I get there is an error in the SQL syntax near where test_time > date.

Comment: @khelwood edited my mistake in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a placeholder

try this:

```
    cursor.execute("""select name, test_time, id from test_table where test_time > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL {0} day)""".format(date))
```

or **SAFE**:

```
    cursor.execute("""select name, test_time, id from test_table where test_time > (CURDATE() - INTERVAL %s day)""", (date,))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, I will accept as answer when I can, thanks.

Comment: Please don't promote string formatting as a solution to passing variables to queries. Using the *DB-API driver's* placeholders is the safe solution.

Comment: I have added a safer way in order to promote the best possible solution